# linux - pbsnodes output - what are the items in 'status'?

Tags: linux, pbs, torque

I have been using the pbsnodes command for a while to collect data on a computing cluster. Recently, I have thought it would be useful to compare number of jobs on a node to it's cpu usage. To me, it seems like the 'loadavg' metric in the status property of pbsnodes' output would be good for this; I can't find a description of what this metric actually is (or any of the other metrics), though, online or anywhere else. Can someone give me a description or a link to a description of the elements in pbsnodes 'status' output?

Comment: `loadave` reports 1 minute bsd load average (see http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/archive/3-0-2/8.1monitoringresources.php)

Comment: Thanks for that response - that documentation seems to be what I am looking for. What do you mean by bsd load average? My system is CentOS 6.3 .

Comment: There are minor differences in the way load averages are computed on different systems. For instance, BSD takes into account only the threads waiting for CPU, while Linux accounts for threads ready to run but waiting for other resources. The authors of Torque documentation decided to highlight the particular algorithm they use across platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load used by MoM is the following:

- On Linux, it is the raw one-minute averaged `loadave` returned by the operating system
- On Windows, it is based on the processor queue length

*Chapter 9.6.5 in PBS Professional 19.2.2 Big Book*

You can find more information about the newer versions of PBSPro and how the `pbsnodes` as well as the `qstat` commands work and what arguments you can add for specific status/vnode state information in the PBSPro Big Book. You can find the PDF at this [link](https://www.pbsworks.com/pdfs/PBS14.2.1_BigBook.pdf).